# Apostrophe in math formula prevents luatex compilation for Slovak

Tags: math-mode, luatex, babel, active-characters

The following example can be compiled with `pdflatex` or `xelatex` without any problems, but with `lualatex`, the compilation comes never to an end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\begin{document}
$f'$
\end{document}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Apparently this was a bug in babel which has been fixed in v. 3.34: https://github.com/latex3/babel/commit/c7883a3a66

Answer (score 7):

slovak.ldf loaded by `\usepackage[slovak]{babel}` is from 2008, it has not be adapted to the unicode engines and is imho completly useless and unsuited.

An alternative is to use the new ini-files from babel:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import=sk, main]{slovak}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{aaa}
$f'$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With this solution, active characters are not available. It is clear that the problem cannot occur without active characters, but I need them.

Comment: which active character do you need for what?

Comment: I need `'a` for *á*.

Comment: Why? can't you simply type á?

Comment: It's for backwards compatibility.

Comment: You could add a similar definition, but  if you switch to lualatex your files won't be backward compatible anyway and imho it would be better to invest a bit time to clean up the files and to avoid all this fragile active char stuff.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “a similar definition”?